# finding intersections in a given range?

Tags: c++, algorithm

assume array of N (N<=100000) elements a1, a2, .... ,an, and you are given range in it L, R where 1<=L<=R<=N, you are required to get number of values in the given range which are divisible by at least one number from a set S which is given also, this set can be any subset of {1,2,....,10}. a fast way must be used because it may ask you for more than one range and more than one S (many queries Q, Q<=100000), so looping on the values each time will be very slow.

i thought of storing numbers of values divisible by each number in the big set {1,2,....,10} in 10 arrays of N elements each, and do cumulative sum to get the number of values divisible by any specific number in any range in O(1) time, for example if it requires to get number of values divisible by at least one of the following: 2,3,5, then i add the numbers of values divisible by each of them and then remove the intersections, but i didn't properly figure out how to calculate the intersections without 2^10 or 2^9 calculations each time which will be also very slow (and possibly hugely memory consuming) because it may be done 100000 times, any ideas ?

Comment: This looks like it is from a programming competition, can you give the link to the source?

Comment: It's a seg-tree problem. You can check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segment-tree), or read about the structure and the algorithm [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/15890)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct. You can use inclusion-exclusion principle and prefix sums to find the answer. There is just one more observation you need to make.

If there's a pair of numbers `a` and `b` in the set such that `a` divides `b`, we can remove `b` without changing the answer to the query (indeed, if `b | x`, then `a | x`). Thus, we always get a set such that no element divides any other one.

The number of such mask is smaller than `2^10`. In facts, it's `102`. Here's the code that computes it:

```
def good(mask):
    for i in filter(lambda b: mask & (1 << (b - 1)), range(1, 11)):
        if (any(i % j == 0 for j in filter(lambda b: mask & (1 << (b - 1)), range(1, i)))):
            return False            
    return True

print(list(filter(good, range(1, 2 ** 10)))))
```

Thus, we the preprocessing requires approximately `100N` operations and numbers to store (it looks reasonably small).

Moreover, there are most `5` elements in any "good" mask (it can be checked using the code above). Thus, we can answer each query using around `2^5` operations.